# How to change Entry cursor color in Xamarin.android

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

In my application need to change xamarin.android entry default color. In my application background image is black and default color of entry in xamarin.android also same color, so need to set different color. Please suggest any idea on that. I am trying fallowing code but I am not getting exact result.

In my xamarin.android project folder contain resource folder inside values folder, we have file 'styles.xml' file. In that is item name 'colorAccent' inside style tag like this.

Sample code:

```
 <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppComa.Light.DarkActionBar">
   <item name="colorAccent">#ffffff</item>
 </style>
```

In colorAccent item name default set as black, now I am change in to white but when run project like this all entry cursor color change to white but with cursor, entry's color also change to white. My requirement is only changing the entry cursor color, remaining is same.

Answer (score 2):

If you're specifying theme for an activity, you can also define custom theme and set **android:textCursorDrawable** to @null. In that case cursor color will be the same as text color.

Here's an example from my working values/Styles.xml, note the last item tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="Project.Main" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

**EDITED**

If you want different cursor color to text color then you need to create EntryRenderer. and put following line in **OnElementChanged** of your Renderer class

```
IntPtr IntPtrtextViewClass = JNIEnv.FindClass(typeof(TextView));
IntPtr mCursorDrawableResProperty = JNIEnv.GetFieldID (IntPtrtextViewClass, "mCursorDrawableRes", "I");
JNIEnv.SetField (Control.Handle, mCursorDrawableResProperty, 0); // replace 0 with a Resource.Drawable.my_cursor
```

Comment: Thanks Pavan. It's work great but I want to set different color different from text color. when I set color code in the place of null it's showing error. How can we set custom color in textCursorDrawable.

Comment: @Deepak, I have updated my answer as per your requirement. 
hopes it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can style your cursor by adding XML file in "Resources\drawable" folder in Android project.

example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
  <size android:width="1dp" />
  <stroke android:color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
</shape>
```

and refer the file in your style.xml in "Resources\values" folder in Android project.

example:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
  <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@drawable/xml_file_name</item>
</style>
```