# What is the name of this component in Xamarin Forms and how can I change its color?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms

I made the color changes in this component `Entry`, but it was missing this standard pink component. I would like to know his name so you can change its color too.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45916849/how-to-change-entry-cursor-color-in-xamarin-android

Answer (score 1):

Resources> styles  #000000
change color according to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the below codes in your activity theme of **Resources/styles**

```
<item name="android:colorControlActivated">#ff0000</item>  //set the color you want
```

Comment: I added this line with any color, but still with the standard pink.